# HTML Check list with PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have following form with action in PHP. I have used Check list to get the project names. If I select the projects in the list it is coming as Array, Array instead of the original value (i.e. Tatvam, Amairo, Vedam).

I am getting the message like this

[image: This is the message I am getting if I select one project]

```
jQuery(".form-js-contact").submit(function () {
    var thisform = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.required-error',thisform).remove();
    var aname   = jQuery("#aname").val();
    var amail   = jQuery("#amail").val();
    var aphone  = jQuery("#aphone").val();
    var acomments   = jQuery("#acomments").val();
    var color   = jQuery("input[name='color[]']").serializeArray();

    var psubject    = jQuery("#psubject").val();

    var data = {'aname':aname,'amail':amail,'aphone':aphone,'acomments':acomments,'psubject':psubject,'color':color};
    if (aname == "") {
        jQuery("#aname").after('<span class="form-description required-error">Required field.</span>');
    }else {
        jQuery("#aname").parent().find('.required-error').remove();
    }
    if (amail == "") {
        jQuery("#amail").after('<span class="form-description required-error">Required field.</span>');
    }else {
        jQuery("#amail").parent().find('.required-error').remove();
    }
    if (aphone == "") {
        jQuery("#aphone").after('<span class="form-description required-error">Required field.</span>');
    }else {
        jQuery("#aphone").parent().find('.required-error').remove();
    }
    if (acomments == "") {
        jQuery("#acomments").after('<span class="form-description required-error">Required field.</span>');
    }else {
        jQuery("#acomments").parent().find('.required-error').remove();
    }



    if (aname != "" && amail != "" && aphone != "" && acomments != "" ) {
        jQuery.post("contact_us_contact.php",data,function (result) {
            if (result == "done") {
                thisform.prepend("<div class='alert-message success-contact'><p><strong>Thank you "+name+"!</strong> We'll be in touch real soon .</p></div>");
                jQuery("#aname").val("");
                jQuery("#amail").val("");
                jQuery("#aphone").val("");
                jQuery("#acomments").val("");

            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

This is my HTML code

```
<form class="form-style form-js-contact" action="contact_us_contact.php" method="post">
                         <input type="hidden" name="psubject" id="psubject" value="Enquiry from Contact Page">
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
<input class=required-item value="" name=aname id=aname aria-required=true placeholder="Your Name*"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" ><input type=email class=required-item id=amail name=amail value="" aria-required=true placeholder="Your Email*"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12" ><input class=required-item aria-required=true id=aphone name=aphone value="" placeholder="Your Phone*"></div>

<div class="col-md-3" style="margin-bottom:10px; "><h4>Projects Interested</h4></div>
<div class="col-md-2" ><input name="color[]" id="color" class="check" type="checkbox" value="Amairo">Amairo</div>
<div class="col-md-2" ><input name="color[]" id="color" class="check" type="checkbox" value="Tatvam">Tatvam</div>
<div class="col-md-2" ><input name="color[]" id="color" class="check" type="checkbox" value="Vedam">Vedam</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12" >
 <textarea name="acomments" id="acomments" class=required-item aria-required=true placeholder="Type Your Message*"></textarea></div>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
<input style=font-size:16px name=submit type=submit value="Send Enquiry" class="submit_buttom buttonColor" id="Main_Contact_Form"></div>
</form>
```

This is my PHP

```
     <?php
     function clean_text($text='') {
     $text = trim($text);
     $text = strip_tags($text);
     $text = addslashes($text);
     $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
     return $text;
     }
   if (!$_POST) {
    die();
  }else {
  if (empty($_POST["aname"]) && empty($_POST["aphone"]) &&      empty($_POST["amail"])&& empty($_POST["acomments"]) ) {
    echo "all_empty";
}else if (empty($_POST["aname"])) {
    echo "empty_name";
}else if (empty($_POST["amail"])) {
    echo "empty_mail";
}else if (empty($_POST["aphone"])) {
    echo "empty_phone";
}else if (empty($_POST["acomments"])) {
    echo "empty_Comments";
}else {     
    $your_email = "mail@mydomain.com";      
    $aname   = clean_text($_POST["aname"]);
    $amail   = clean_text($_POST["amail"]);
    $aphone  = clean_text($_POST["aphone"]);
    $acomments   = clean_text($_POST["acomments"]);
    $wname = $_POST['color'];
    $psubject    = clean_text($_POST["psubject"]);
    $subject  = "$psubject"; 

    $headers  = "From: leads@mydomain.in". "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'. "\r\n";
    $msg      = "New Message \n\r <br>";
    $msg     .= "Name : \t $aname \r\n <br>";
    $msg     .= "Email : \t $amail \r\n<br>";       
    $msg    .= "Phone : \t $aphone \r\n<br>";   
    $msg    .= "Message : \t $acomments \r\n<br>";
    if (isset($wname)) {
    $msg    .= "Project(s) Interested: \r\n";
    $msg    .= "<ul> \r\n";
    foreach ($wname as $color){
    $msg    .="<li>" .$color. "</li>  \r\n";
 }

    $msg    .= "</ul>";

     } // isset

    echo "done";
    $done = @mail($your_email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: You may want to provide more information on what you want to achieve or what is your exact problem. Otherwise it will be difficult to help you solve this problem.

Comment: Hi jrenk, Thanks for quick reply. What i exactly need is the check  list is not working properly. I am not getting the values from checklist even it is checked also. Could you please update me the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking value of color in jquery with id `jQuery("#color").val();` and as per HTML rule there is only one id with same name so you will get only one value. You have to replace like

```
> jQuery

var color = jQuery("input[name='color[]']").serializeArray();
```

and then you will get the all the values of color in PHP Code `$wname = $_POST['color'];`

Comment: Could you please tell me why the values are coming as Array instead of original values i have given in the value tag. Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you will get the color data in array. You need to parse the array in ul li

Comment: Hi Pathik I have updated new code in jQuery and PHP. please check it and let me know the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your php code replace this

```
$wname      = $_POST['color'];
```

with

```
$wname      = implode( ",", $_POST['color']);
```

as you are passing `name="color[]"` from HTML as an array.

Comment: Hi Syed, I used the same thing but i am getting he message without the project  

Name :   Tester
Email :          test@testmail.com
Phone :          123456789
Message :        Test

Answer (score 0):

Saw an error on your code

The following seems wrong

```
if (isset($_POST['wname'])) {...}
```

I believe it should be

```
if (isset($wname)) {...}
```

Comment: Hi Raz, I used the same thing but i am getting he message without the project Name : Tester Email : test@testmail.com Phone : 123456789 Message : Test